# SQL: Efficient distinct count by category over moving date window

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, data-science

**The problem**

I have a large amount of card transaction data in SQL tables (SQL Server). Each row has the following information:

Main table

| TxnDate | UserID | SpendCategory | Amount | AgeGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2018 | ID1 | Category1 | 100 | 18-29 |
| 02/03/2019 | ID2 | Category2 | 20 | 40-49 |
| 05/03/2019 | ID3 | Category1 | 200 | 30-39 |
| 08/03/2019 | ID1 | Category2 | 300 | 18-29 |
| 10/03/2019 | ID2 | Category2 | 300 | 40-49 |

What I need is to find the number of unique users who have had transactions in a particular SpendCategory, or in particular SpendCategory AgeGroup combination, over a moving window of 30 days (e.g. 1st Jan - 30th Jan, 2nd Jan - 31st Jan). So my output should be a table like:

| TxnDate | SpendCategory | UniqueUsers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2018 | Category1 | 800 |
| 01/01/2018 | Category2 | 200 |
| 02/01/2018 | Category1 | 600 |
| 02/01/2018 | Category2 | 300 |

Or:

| TxnDate | SpendCategory | AgeGroup | UniqueUsers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2018 | Category1 | 18-29 | 800 |
| 01/01/2018 | Category2 | 30-39 | 200 |

etc

**What I've already tried**

I have a solution that works, however it is too slow and inefficient to run on larger datasets (e.g. hundreds of millions of rows).

I first create a table with all the date and SpendCategory/Age combinations that are needed, #all_rows:

| TxnDate | SpendingCategory |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2019 | Category1 |
| 01/01/2019 | Category 2 |
| 02/01/2019 | Category1 |
| 02/01/2019 | Category 2 |

Which I can then use to run the following query:

```sql
--Create example table
CREATE TABLE #main (TxnDate date, UserID varchar(100), SpendCategory varchar(100));

INSERT INTO #main
VALUES ('01/01/2019', 'ID1', 'Category1'),
('01/01/2019', 'ID2', 'Category1'),
('02/06/2019', 'ID1', 'Category2'),
('02/06/2019', 'ID2', 'Category2')

--Create lookup table
CREATE TABLE #category_lookup (SpendCategory varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #category_lookup
VALUES ('Category1'), ('Category2')

--Create #all_rows
DECLARE @max_date date, @min_date date

SELECT @max_date = MAX(TxnDate) FROM #Main
SELECT @min_date = MIN(TxnDate) FROM #Main;

WITH ListDates(TxnDate) as (
SELECT @min_date AS DATE
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, TxnDate) AS DATE
FROM ListDates
WHERE TxnDate < @max_date)

SELECT DISTINCT T1.TxnDate, T2.SpendCategory
INTO #all_rows
FROM ListDates AS T1
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT SpendCategory
   FROM #category_lookup) AS T2

--Find unique users
SELECT t.TxnDate, t.SpendCategory,
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) AS UniqueUsers
       FROM #main
      WHERE TxnDate > DATEADD(DAY, -30, t.TxnDate)
      AND TxnDate <= t.TxnDate
      AND SpendCategory = t.SpendCategory
      GROUP BY SpendCategory) AS UniqueUsers
FROM #all_rows as t
```

[Fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/Tk7PY9-u)

This returns the correct result but is far too slow. Does anyone have an alternative approach that would be more efficient please?

Edit: Adding information as requested in the comments. Unfortunately, I work for a highly restrictive organisation so I do not have access to the query execution plan. I have added more details to the code example above to make it reproducible. Main is generally either a CTE or a temp table containing a subset of the full data available in a permanent table.

We have indexes set up on the Main table, they're non-clustered. The most relevant index to this query is a composite index on TxnDate, SpendCategory and UserID. The code takes at least a day to run on a sample of ~400 million rows, we'd like it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Performance tuning for SQL queries cannot be done piecemeal, trying to do so is just a random guessing game.  To advise you properly we need a lot more specific information, the most useful of which would be the [Actual Query Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16) for this query.  Also, it would help greatly to have the table and index definitions and the complete code for your query, how long it takes to run, and how much faster you need it to be.

Comment: For best performance, I suggest that you create an index like `CREATE INDEX IX_Main_... ON Main(SpendingCategory, Txndate)` or even better `CREATE INDEX IX_Main_... ON Main(SpendingCategory, Txndate) INCLUDE(UserID)`, if you don't already have one. Your query optimizer will thank you for it.

Comment: Although I don't think it makes a difference, you can drop the `GROUP BY SpendingCategory` in your subselect. You have already filtered on a single SpendingCategory value, and the `COUNT(...)` already triggers a grouping. I also suggest that you alias the `FROM Main M` and add an `M.` qualifier to the appropriate columns just so there is no chance of accidentally referencing an outer select column, when an inner column was intended.

Comment: Thanks for your comments both, I have added the extra information requested that I can. My organisation is very restrictive with query/execution plans which is why I have not been able to provide those. I will try altering my indexes which are slightly different to your suggestions and see if that improves performance.

Comment: Are all of your dates just plain dates or are they date/times? If the latter, are you willing to accept granularity at just the date level? this is somewhat a prerequisite for teh approach posted by @Cetin Basoz.

Comment: Please fix you posted query to fix syntax and other errors. You can paste it into a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-). Make the necessary changes until it runs. Add some indentation for the subqueries while you are there. Once done, update your post above with the corrected code. Also include the new generated link to the fiddle.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy code, fixed and have added a link to the fiddle. Yes I am happy with granularity at just the date level.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data distribution this might be faster:

```
SELECT t.TxnDate, t.SpendingCategory, tmp.UniqueUsers
FROM #all_rows as t
cross apply (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) AS UniqueUsers
    FROM Main m
    WHERE m.TxnDate > DATEADD(DAY, -30, t.TxnDate)
      AND m.TxnDate <= t.TxnDate
      AND m.SpendingCategory = t.SpendingCategory
 ) AS tmp(UniqueUsers);
```

EDIT: And calling a function on every row is not feasible, it is better to have that beforehand:

```
select DateAdd(day, -30, txnDate) as FromDate, 
       txnDate as ToDate, SpendingCategory
into #AllRows
from #all_Rows;

SELECT t.TxnDate, t.SpendingCategory, tmp.UniqueUsers
FROM #allrows as t
cross apply (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) AS UniqueUsers
    FROM Main m
    WHERE m.TxnDate > T.fromDate
      AND m.TxnDate <= t.ToDate
      AND m.SpendingCategory = t.SpendingCategory
 ) AS tmp(UniqueUsers);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, moving the DateAdd function to the outer table definitely makes sense. I will try switching to cross apply and report back too, is there a particular reason that could be faster than the subquery?

Comment: @user228570, your question have changed since I wrote my answer, as of now it is somewhat outdated. I didn't for example know how you were generating #all_rows content. I need to think on it a bit and unfortunately I am busy at the moment but I will later.

Comment: Apologies if the additional details have changed things! I think some of your suggestions are still relevant. If you did have any further thoughts I'd be very grateful!

Comment: @user228570, I couldn't come up with something better. Maybe just skip creating #all_rows and do the cross apply with applying last 30 days per row only (would only recover the time for creating #all_rows + skip rows where there were no entries).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each row could be scanned 30 times.
I would use a helper table to accumulate distinct values per each day and then scan that smaller table something like this:

```
SELECT m.TxnDate, m.SpendingCategory, AgeGroup, COUNT(DISTINCT m.UserId) UniqueUsers  
INTO #DailyCounts 
FROM Main m
GROUP BY m.TxnDate, m.SpendingCategory, m.AgeGroup

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX tmpDalyCount on #DailyCounts(TxnDate, SpendingCategory, AgeGroup)

SELECT t.TxnDate, t.SpendingCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT dc.UniqueUsers) UniqueUsers
FROM #All_Rows t
INNER JOIN #DailyCounts dc
    ON dc.TxnDate > DATEADD(DAY, -30, t.TxnDate)
       AND dc.TxnDate <= t.TxnDate
GROUP BY t.TxnDate, t.SpendingCategory
```

The same table will help to create both outputs

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately I don't think this will produce the desired result, by grouping up the user IDs by day we lose the ability to identify duplicate IDs on different days within the same period i.e. with this ID1 on 01/01/2019 and ID1 on 02/01/2019 would be counted as two different values.

Comment: I was about to suggest similar to the above, but with just (distinct...) `UserId` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT m.UserId)` I would also recommend that the index place `SpendingCategory` before `TxnDate`.  Next preprocess that into a #ThirtyDayCounts table that does calculate `COUNT(DISTINCT UserId)` for each SpendingCategory and (ending) TxnDate. Index that one too. That could then be used in the final select.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggested approach. This follows the same approach as in Cetin Basoz's earlier answer, where user statistics are summarized and indexed ahead of the final query.

```
-- First summarize distinct UserIDs, Age groups, and SpendingCategory by date
SELECT
    DISTINCT CAST(TxnDate AS DATE) AS TxnDate,
    SpendingCategory, AgeGroup, UserId
INTO #DailyUsers 
FROM Main

CREATE INDEX IX_tmpDailyUsers
    ON #DailyUsers(TxnDate, SpendingCategory, AgeGroup) INCLUDE(UserId)

-- Determine needed date range
DECLARE @MinDate DATE, @MaxDate DATE
SELECT @MinDate = MIN(TxnDate), @MaxDate = MAX(TxnDate)
FROM #DailyUsers

-- For each date, summarize the last 30 days worth of user activity
;WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT @MinDate AS Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, D.DATE)
    FROM Dates D
    WHERE D.Date < @MaxDate
)
SELECT
    D.EndDate, U.SpendingCategory, U.AgeGroup,
    COUNT(DISTINCT m.UserId) AS UniqueUsers
INTO #ThirtyDayCounts
FROM Dates D
JOIN #DailyUsers U
    ON U.TxnDate > DATEADD(day, -30, D.EndDate)
    AND U.TxnDate <= D.EndDate
GROUP BY D.EndDate, U.SpendingCategory, U.AgeGroup

CREATE INDEX IX_tmpThirtyDayCounts
  ON #ThirtyDayCounts(EndDate, SpendingCategory)

-- Now pull it together with what should be a simple efficient join
SELECT t.TxnDate, t.SpendingCategory, tdc.AgeGroup, tdc.UniqueUsers
FROM #All_Rows t
JOIN #ThirtyDayCounts tdc
    ON tdc.SpendingCategory = t.SpendingCategory
    AND tdc.EndDate = CAST(t.TxnDate AS DATE)
```

(Note: The above is untested. If you spot errors, please comment and I will correct my post.)